# Regex to get the first number after a certain string followed by any data until the number

Tags: php, regex

I have a piece of data, retrieved from the database and containing information I need. Text is entered in a free form so it's written in many different ways. The only thing I know for sure is that I'm looking for the first number after a given string, but after that certain string (before the number) can be any text as well.

I tried this (where `mytoken` is the string I know for sure its there) but this doesn't work.

```
/(mytoken|MYTOKEN)(.*)\d{1}/
/(mytoken|MYTOKEN)[a-zA-Z]+\d{1}/
/(mytoken|MYTOKEN)(.*)[0-9]/
/(mytoken|MYTOKEN)[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]/
```

Even `mytoken` can be written in capitals, lowercase or a mix of capitals and lowercase character. Can the expression be case insensitive?

Comment: `'/mytoken.*?(\d+)/i'`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, +1. I've combined your answer with Ibarros's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need any lazy matching since you want to match **any number of non-digit symbols up to the first digit**. It is better done with a `\D*`:

```
/(mytoken)(\D*)(\d+)/i
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iA2wY4/1)

The pattern details:

- `(mytoken)` - Group 1 matching `mytoken` (case insensitively, as there is a `/i` modifier)
- `(\D*)` - Group 2 matching zero or more characters other than a digit
- `(\d+)` - Group 3 matching 1 or more digits.

Note that `\D` also matches newlines, `.` needs a DOTALL modifier to match across newlines.

Comment: I believe this is a better suiting answer to my need, therefore I'll accept this answer. Thanks for the time you take to explain why it's better and writing the expression guided with a human readable explanation.

Comment: Glad to help. Also, I forgot to add that you should consider removing the capturing groups `()` from those parts of the pattern that you won't be using later - in order not to clutter the final result with captures.

Comment: Good point! Eventually I'm interested in the number (since it's a score from a calculation) and the raw matching string (for sample checks)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a lazy quantifier.  You can do that by putting a question mark after the star quantifier in the regex: `.*?`. Otherwise, the numbers will be matched by the dot operator until the last number, which will be matched by `\d`.

Regex: `/(mytoken|MYTOKEN)(.*?)\d/`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gO3aF0/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the opposite:

```
/(mytoken|MYTOKEN)(\D+)(\d)/
```

This says: mytoken, followed by anything **not a number**, followed by a number. The (lazy) dot-star-soup is not always your best bet. The desired number will be in `$3` in this example.